# Use formBuilder in a foreach to generate multiple fields

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I'm developing a project with Symfony 5, currently busy with an import of data from CSV to a database. It's requested to offer the client the possibility to choose, which data from the CSV is corresponding to which field of the database.

For example, I want to import users to the database.

The array of fields from the database:

```
$databaseFields = ['username', 'email', 'lastname', 'firstname'];
```

The array of headers, frome the CSV:

```
$headersCsvArray = ['email', 'username', 'lastName'];
```

Based on this 2 arrays, I need to build a form:

```
foreach ($databaseFields as $databaseField) {
    $builder->add('extraFields', ChoiceType::class,
        [
            'label'       => $databaseField,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a column from the excel file',
            'choices'     => $headersCsvArray,
            'multiple'    => false,
            'expanded'    => false,
            'required'    => false
        ]
    );
}
```

To be clear, I need an input for each field of the User entity, with a dropdown with every header from the CSV.

This form is link to an ImportUserFormModel, with basically nothing for the moment:

```
class ImportUserFormModel
{
    public $extraFields;
}
```

The result I need when I do $form->getData('extraData'):

```
$importDatas = [
    'username' => 
    [
        'username' => true,
        'emails'   => false,
        'lastName' => false
    ], 
    'email' => 
    [
        'username' => false,
        'emails'   => true,
        'lastName' => false
    ], 
    'lastname' => 
    [
        'username' => false,
        'emails'   => false,
        'lastName' => true
    ],
    'firstname' => 
    [
        'username' => false,
        'emails'   => false,
        'lastName' => true
    ],
];
```

Where the TRUE value is the one choose from the select dropdown.

Here is the result I actually have:

[image]

So I'm asking myself: Is it possible to use the foreach here?

Comment: Isn't it because you add the same field name at each iteration of your foreach ?

Comment: @jona303 probably ! I should add an iterator, but I don't know how to handle this with my  ImportUserFormModel. And I just did
I have this error: Can't get a way to read the property "extraFields0" in class "App\Form\Model\ImportUserFormModel".

Comment: If your database fields are defined, why don't declare them as properties of your model ? Should it be dynamic ?

Comment: @jona303 yes, I'm trying to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want it dynamic this could be a solution.
Create a Model for your extra field too, like

```
class ExtraField {
    private $databseField;
    private $csvField;

    // ...
}
```

And in your base model use it as a collection

```
class ImportUserFormModel
{
    private $extraFields;

    public getFields(): ExtraField[] { 
        // ...
    }
    public addField(ExtraField $extraField) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Create a FormType for your ExtraField model and another one for your base model where `extraFields` is a CollectionType.

Then before the form creation define the fields in your model

```
$importUserFormModel = new ImportUserFormModel();

foreach ($databaseFields as $databaseField) {
    $extraField = new ExtraField();
    $extraField->setDatabaseField($databaseField);
    $importUserFormModel->addExtraField($extraField);
}

$form = $this->createForm(ImportUserFormModelType::class, $importUserFormModel);
// ....
```

The thing i'm not sure about is how to put the name of the database field in the label of the form field but you could template it.

Comment: Well I'm working alone, my nose is the code and I did not think of this king of solution...
I'm gonna try this solution, and I'll let you know about the result.

Comment: Forgot about this, you can set the choices values as an option of the extrafieldtype